# CodeIgniter: select datetime gives wierd return

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

This is mine code, I asked the end_date from the tblTest. end_date is a datetime. 
Here is the code, but it give me an error:

```
$this->db->select(date('end_date'));
$this->db->where('topActive', 'true');
$this->db->order_by('end_date');
$this->db->group_by('end_date');
$q = $this->db->get('tblTest');
```

**Error**:

```
Unknown column 'UTC1107_07pm30UTC' in 'field list'
SELECT `UTC1107_07pm30UTC` 
FROM (`tblTest`) 
WHERE `topActive` = 'true' 
GROUP BY `UTC1107_07pm30UTC` 
ORDER BY `UTC1107_07pm30UTC`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your select method, you're passing a date object. this method accepts the names of the columns that you need returned. `end_date` is your column name, so use that.

```
$this->db->select('end_date');
```

**UPDATE**

This is the query that ended up working:

```
$this->db->select("DATE(end_date) as my_end_date", FALSE);
$this->db->where('topActive', 'true');
$this->db->order_by('my_end_date');
$this->db->group_by('my_end_date');
$q = $this->db->get('tblTest');
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but the problem is (didn't write this above). I want to group_by the date and the 'end_date' is a datetime (Y-m-d H:i:s) and I only want the date (Y-m-d)

Comment: Oh, ok - then you need to pass the `date` function as a string so that it will be interpreted as the mysql `DATE` function and not the php `date` function and pass `false` as the second parameter to select.  `$this->db->select("DATE('end_date')", FALSE);`  -- p.s. by convention, I'd uppercase the mysql function to help differentiate it from php functions.

Comment: Sorry, but it doenst work, this is what i get from a print_r:
[date('end_date')] =>

Comment: oops, alias it:  `$this->db->select("DATE('end_date') as my_end_date", FALSE);`  -- then change `end_date` to `my_end_date` in your group_by and order_by methods.

Comment: Still nothing: [my_end_date] =>

Comment: what does the query end up looking like?

Comment: the query returns nothing. Its empty

Comment: OK, try removing the quotes around `end_date`: `$this->db->select("DATE(end_date) as my_end_date", FALSE);`

Comment: and how do I use the 'select' if I want more than just 1 column selected $this->db->select("end_date, someThingElse");

Comment: You can have multiple select methods, or you can just append column names to the current select:  `$this->db->select("DATE(end_date) as my_end_date", FALSE);  $this->db->select('other_column');`  -- or --  `$this->db->select("DATE(end_date) as my_end_date, other_column", FALSE);`